# Use SUBTOTAL only where column contains a value

Tags: excel

I am currently using the following subtotal `SUBTOTAL(9,b:b)` to cat a total on my filtered data.

Column A contains a year of either 16,17,18 or 19.

I would like to only count the subtotal if column A contains 16 so

`=if(a:a = 16, SUBTOTAL(9,b:b)` or something simular

Comment: If column A _equals_ 16?  or _contains_ 16?  Have you tried `SUMIFS()`?

Comment: @Marc - SUMIFS will not ignore filtered rows. OP - see [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-visible-rows-only-with-criteria) perhaps.

Comment: Column A. Is 16. So its basically grouping column A and only performing the subtotal on those that are 16 and ignoring the ones that are 17 18 or 18. I want to get a subtotal on each year you see so subtotal on those that are 16...subtotL on those that are 17 etc so I can see if the stats change year on year

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:A1000)-1,,1,1))*(A1:A1000=16)*(B1:B1000))`

Comment: One note on the formula above, you need to make sure there are no text in the range provided for column B.  So if your data has headers, start all the references with row 2 not row 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can "fake" the `SUBTOTAL()` function.  Say we have data like:

[image]

and we want to filter the data and only add values in column **B** that correspond to *16* in column **A**.  In **C2** enter:

```
=SUBTOTAL(3,$B2:$B2)
```

and copy downward.  Then filter column **B** for positive only:

[image]

The cool thing about column **C** is that it is *1* if the row is visible and *0* if the row is hidden.  Therefore:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B20)*(C2:C20))
```

will yield the same result as `=subtotal(9,b:b)` and:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A20=16)*(B2:B20)*(C2:C20))
```

will apply the column **A** restriction.

[image]

Comment: Great hack Thanks